# Getting the SelectedItem as DataContext for a completly independent Uielement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, selecteditem

I began to make a program in c# using wpf and the mvvm pattern to learn this program language. I feel sorry that I finally have problems I can't solve using Google. But I try being precise.

At first I [present](http://s7.directupload.net/images/120601/3x5gli87.png) you the GUI, so I can explain my problems more easily.

The xaml file of the MainWindow comes [here](http://code.google.com/p/lolscripts/source/browse/trunk/MainWindow.xaml).

As you see, it's not a serious and important program, I just made it to learn some techniques.

*Now comes my **main question**:*
I need the SelectedItem Property of the second ListView(Consumables) in the footer. I thought this wouldn't be a serious problem cause I can just bind it to the selected item using relative path and the name of the listview. This didn't work and caused a null reference error as soon as I added an item to this listview. I double checked the code and I am sure I haven't made something wrong there. So I thought the problem is, that it's kind of a descendant ui element.

My next try was to create a new property in my main view model which is bound to the selected item. You can find this in line 136. But as I found out, this causes me a System.NullReferenceException too if i click on an item. I think it's because this property is read only. I don't know what to do. **Isn't there any other possibility to bind the SelectedItem as DataContext for the footer**?

*My Second Question is about line 27*. The TabControl should always select the first Tab automatically. But it makes it only every second time. It's quite funny. If I scroll down the Champion Combo Box, the first tab goes: selected - unselected - selected - ...

*My third and last Question is about 72* which is similar to line 50 (The DataContext is the same too) But the ICommand of the ContextMenu of the itemtemplate you see line 50 works, whereas the contextmenu (l. 72) does not call the Icommand. Weird.

It's a fun project, so I can provide you the source code if my information are not enough.
--Sorry, only two hyperlinks allowed--

Please help me. I am just a bit confused by this unsuspected behaviour. I haven't found anything that could help me and I'm sorry if the answers of these questions will be simple :P

Just to emphasize it: The main question is the only one I really need an answer for. The second one could be solved programatically. And to solve the third one, I could just remove this feature.

I'm happy for EVERY HINT!

Comment: split your questions into multiple parts (multiple questions) with sample code for each question. It's a big question and difficult to read in one go. People may also have answer for only one of your questions so it also makes it easier for them to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't gone through the entire question but you should bind selected item to your view model property (two way binding) and then bind another UIElement to this view model property (probably one way binding or check for value equality as to not cause stackoverflow exception)

Comment: If you would have read the line 136 of the xaml file, you would have seen that i already did this. It gives me a System.NullReferenceException as soon as I add an Item. TwoWay Binding AND OneWayToSource tested. Thanks anyway.

Comment: try to put a value converter in there and see what is causing null reference.

Comment: Sorry, I can make you a video if you want -.- All I can see if i debug is, that it sets the selected item properly, then raises the "propertychanged" event, and then the selected item gets called ~three times. Without clicking again, the selected item gets saved again, and called ~8 times, now i get the same amount of null reference errors. i didnt skip any debugging skips, so it the calls are coming from the gui. (The selectedItem isnt used in the c# code at all) -> using OneWayToSource causes the same Error!

Comment: Weird. Now sth other happens. As soon as I select the item, the tab gets unselected. If i click on this tab, the same exceptions happen. I wrote some debug messages in the Converter: [link]http://privatepaste.com/894547f602 sorry its in german, but it should you should see where it goes